# How can I dynamically select the datatype of a new column according to the data to be filled in

Tags: mysql

A table is created via a C# script. The script analyzes INSERT statements from another source and creates a CREATE TABLE sql statement out of it which is then executed in MYSQL. The columns are created as VARCHAR only. The number and name of the columns can vary from time to time.

I want to dynamically (in a MYSQL stored procedure) create a new table which contains the columns of the first table. I want to create the datatype for the new columns so that it fits best to the data contained in the old columns. For example, the old column is of datatype VARCHAR, but only contains numbers - so my new column should be of datatype INT.

Is there a way to solve this dynamically with MYSQL?

Or should I extend the C# script to find out the best datatype for each column and create the first table already with the right column datatypes? I have the feeling c# offers me more possibilities to do that.

Comment: I don't know how strong your SQL is, but I would say that doing this in C# would be far easier, checking types is a more common place function in C#. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Thank you it seems my feeling is right- I am not that strong in SQL and I already found some good examples for C# in the net.